# SQL: Select attribute from row given primary key

Tags: sql, database

New to SQL, I need to be able to retrieve an attribute from a row given a primary key. Take this table, for example:
[image]

Lets say I'm given the CustomerID 3. What would the SQL query be if I wanted to retrieve the Country associated with that ID?

(table is from https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

Comment: select country from my_table where  customerID = 3;

Comment: Ah, thanks! Didn't realize it was so simple!

Answer (score 0):

select country from my_table where customerID in(3);

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
SELECT Country FROM YourTable WHERE CustomerID = 3;
```